# In C++ threads, should I pass shared_ptr by value or reference?

Tags: c++

This page on [Thread Safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-safety-in-the-cpp-standard-library?view=msvc-160) by Microsoft says `shared_ptr` should be used even if there are multiple copies sharing the same object.

So does this mean that both of the following are acceptable? I've tried both and they appear to work fine.

**EDIT**: The actual business objective is to get string updates from the long running thread to the main thread. I figured I should use `shared_ptr` since `string` is not thread safe. Don't care about ownership honestly.

**Option 1 (Passing reference):**

```
auto status = std::make_shared<std::string>();
auto f = [&status]() {
    ...
  *status = "current status";
    ...
};

std::thread t{f};

while(true) {
  std::cout << *status << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
  if (*status == "completed") break;
}

t.join();
```

**Option 2 (Making a copy):**

```
auto status = std::make_shared<std::string>();
auto f = [](std::shared_ptr<std::string> s) {
    ...
  *s= "current status";
    ...
};

std::thread t{f, status};

while(true) {
  std::cout << *status << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
  if (*status == "completed") break;
}

t.join();
```

**EDIT2:** So apparently both these approaches are wrong for what I'm trying to achieve. I need to use `std::mutex` ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)) and not muck around with `shared_ptr`. See second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66455013/1287554).

Comment: you start a single thread that writes, ie there cannot be any data race in your example. Its too simplified. Though you just need to add a second thread to make it demonstrate the issue

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Sorry, I thought it was self explanatory. I can edit the question.

Comment: it is "self-explanatory" that there are no multthreading issues when you have only a single thread ;)

Comment: Passing by reference will not increment the shared_ptr's refcount. If you want the thread to be able to ensure the lifetime of the shared_ptr lasts as long as the thread does then it needs its own copy.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly valid to have multiple instances of `std::shared_ptr` that all reference the same object and share ownership. In fact that's the point of having a `std::shared_ptr`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Point taken :). Hope the update makes sense.

Comment: @churill I'm not sure if using multiple instances of `std::shared_ptr` is thread safe.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It doesn't really need to ensure lifetime. I just need the long running thread to pass status updates back to the main thread in a thread safe way.

Comment: @PlastyGrove It's not. But it's still ok to have multiple copies of a shared_ptr even if it's not thread safe. Neither of the options in your question are thread safe, but you should definately copy the shared_ptr. I would use options 1 but capture by value.

Comment: actually thats orthogonal: You decide to pass copy or ref based on ownership considerations. The underlying pointer has no synchronization at all in your code and writing from two threads causes UB

Comment: To answer your question *So does this mean that both of the following are acceptable?*  No, both are unacceptable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically, threads may outlive the scope where they are created. In such case, any local variable captured by reference may be destroyed while the thread is still running. If this is the case, then you should not capture by reference.

Furthermore, modifying a shared pointer object in one thread and accessing in another without synchronisation results in undefined behaviour. If that is what you're doing, then you should access the pointer using `std::atomic_load`/`atomic_store` functions, or simply copy the pointer into each thread. Note that you can capture by copy:

```
auto f = [status]() {
```

---

Furthermore, the shared pointer provides no extra thread safety to accessing the pointed object beyond keeping the ownership alive and ensuring it gets deleted exactly once. If the pointed type is not atomic, then modifying it in one thread and accessing in another without synchronisation results in undefined behaviour. If that is what you're doing, you need to use mutexes or something similar. Or copy the pointed object itself into each thread.

Regarding the edited question: Your examples apply to this last case. Both of them have undefined behaviour. You need synchronisation.

Comment: I see - so I can't pretend `shared_ptr` is a convenient holder for thread safe `string`?

Comment: @PlastyGrove `std::shared_ptr` is great for keeping a string alive for the duration of a thread. It's not magic that makes everything thread safe.

Comment: Modifying in one thread and accessing in another without synchronisation is race condition, not UB.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Standard says thus: `If a side effect on a memory location ([intro.memory]) is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same memory location or a value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location, and they are not potentially concurrent ([intro.multithread]), the behavior is undefined.` In short, *data race* is UB.

Comment: "Furthermore, the shared pointer provides no extra thread safety to accessing the pointed object" This can be extended: It provides no extra safety to the raw pointer to the object. This is a commonly seen misassumption, that a sharedPtr is thread-safe as long as you do not touch/affect the data the sharedPtr is pointing to.

Answer (score 8):

It is weird to accept `shared_ptr` by reference as you lose the whole point of using `shared_ptr` in the first place. You may just use a raw pointer instead.

There are cases when accepting by reference of `shared_ptr` is legitimate but if you give a reference of it to a thread then it will cause UB once that instance of the `shared_ptr` is destroyed and the thread still uses the `shared_ptr`.

Primary purpose of `shared_ptr` is to manage lifetime of the object. If you pass a reference of it to a thread then you throw away the whole purpose and advantages of the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Why passing a shared_ptr as reference (in general, not speaking of threads) lose the whole point of using it? Obviously, passing a reference and deleting it object will cause UB, but isn't that the case for all references?

Comment: @AdrianMaire you pass a `shared_ptr` as a reference only if you want to do changes to the `shared_ptr` itself (if you want to change the object managed by this particular `shared_ptr` and this is a rare use-case), if you want to manipulate the object that is managed by the `shared_ptr` you pass the `shared_ptr` by value (if the function requires ownership - which can be likely for a thread because a thread might break the top down aproach), or you pass the raw pointer or reference to the managed object if the function does not need ownership.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: `shared_ptr` copies ensure that the object in the shared_ptr is not deleted while still being used. If you don't copy the `shared_ptr` then you don't have that guarantee. So there are two possibilities: Either the function that takes a `shared_ptr` reference passes it on to other functions transitively and one of them finally takes a copy, or that doesn't happen. If it doesn't happen you might as well pass a raw pointer to the function, as it never participates in ownership. If it eventually does get copied then the interface is misleading, as the reference suggests it doesn't.

Comment: @t.niese I did not say it is a good practice (actually it's better to pass by value as you mention), but his sentence indicates some wrong assumptions of the shared_ptr.

Comment: @Corristo shared_ptr keep the heap object until last copy is deleted, in thread-safe context. For instance, if you know that only a deep call will make a copy of the shared_ptr, it makes sense to pass it as reference to avoid X copies of shared_ptr in each call while only one is required (maybe not good practice, but still valid rational). shared_ptr implements RAII to encapsulate a heap object, this has value whether or not you follow the good practice of passing it by value/reference.

Comment: A guess where the confusion here might arise from: I think, one should strictly distinguish here between "by reference" and "by const reference" and the kind of forwarding: lambda capturing vs. function parameters. Forwarding const references of sharedPtrs to functions makes totally sense for many scenarios as long as the context itself is thread-safe with focus on the pointer's usage.

Comment: @AdrianMaire *it makes sense to pass it as reference to avoid X copies of shared_ptr in each call while only one is required* You don't need to make X copies, you can move the one copy you made.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a reference you can't detach the thread.

for example, this program will be crashed:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
void f1()
{
  auto status = std::make_shared<std::string>();
  auto f = [&status]() 
  {
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); 
    *status = "current status";
  };
  std::thread t{f};
  t.detach();
}
int main() { 
  f1();
  std::string status="other status";//use the frame
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); 
  std::cout<<status<<std::endl; //check the frame
}
```

Comment: Note that "will be crashed" is an optimistic outcome. If you're unlucky, it may appear to run fine.

Comment: "cant detach" isnt quite right. One could add something that ensures that `status` is only used as long it is alive also in a detached thread

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a reference to `status` the lambda, it means that you would need make sure yourself that the lambda does not outlive the `status` variable.

Imagine that we would want to move the thread creation to a separate function:

```
std::thread
spawn_thread( std::shared_ptr< std::string > status )
{
    auto f = [&status]( ) {
        // Adding a sleep to make sure this gets executed after we exit spawn_thread function.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 500 ) );
        *status = "current status";
    };

    std::thread t{f};
    return t;
}

int
main( )
{
    auto status = std::make_shared< std::string >( );
    auto thread = spawn_thread( status );

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << *status << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 1000 ) );
        if ( *status == "completed" )
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    thread.join( );
}
```

Running this code will most likely result in a crash, since variable `status` (not the shared data behind it) gets out of scope before we access it within the lambda.

Of course we could pass the reference to status to the `spawn_thread` function, but then we propagate the problem further - now the caller of `spawn_thread` needs to make sure that this variable outlives the thread.

`std::shared_ptr` is designed for the cases when you do not want to manually control the lifetime of the object passed around, but in order for it to work you need to pass it by value so that the internal mechanism keeps count of the number of `shared_ptr` instances.

Keep in mind that while passing around and copying `shared_ptr` is thread safe, concurrent reads and writes of the value stored inside it is not.